# Code Efficiency - Multiple Queries w/ Situational Reaction

Tags: php, sql

My question is one of efficiency or best practice. I am currently passing several values from a user input form to a "processing" page via form POST. One of the goals of the processing page is to validate against duplicate entries (in the database) prior to submitting any new data or changes.

I have opted for 3 separate queries against the database to check for duplicate values so that I (a novice programmer) know how to call and react to each of them separately. I do feel as though there must be a better way to do this, perhaps with a single SELECT statement and then splitting it into separate arrays once the data is retrieved. I'm just not sure how to pull that off.

If duplicates are found I will send the end-user back to the form with their entered values pre-populated in their respective form fields, marking the duplicate via CSS. If no duplicates are found I will push data to the database as a new record or UPDATE.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $asset = isset($_POST['asset']) ? $_POST['asset'] : null;
    $alias = isset($_POST['alias']) ? $_POST['alias'] :null;
    $make = isset($_POST['make']) ? $_POST['make'] : null;
    $model = isset($_POST['model']) ? $_POST['model'] : null;
    $rid = isset($_POST['rid']) ? $_POST['rid'] : null;
    $pdate = isset($_POST['pdate']) ? $_POST['pdate'] : null;
    $term = isset($_POST['term']) ? $_POST['term'] : null;
    $serialnumber = isset($_POST['serialnumber']) ? $_POST['serialnumber'] : null;
    $notes = isset($_POST['notes']) ? $_POST['notes'] : null;

    $dupasset=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_Portables WHERE Portable_Asset_Number = :asset');
    $duprid=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_Portables WHERE Portable_LID = :rid');
    $dupserial=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_Portables WHERE Portable_Serial_Number = :serialnumber');

    $dupasset->bindValue(':asset', $asset, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $duprid->bindValue(':rid', $rid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $dupserial->bindValue(':serialnumber', $serialnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $dupasset->execute();
    $duprid->execute();
    $dupserial->execute();


    $assetcount = $dupasset->rowcount();
    $ridcount = $duprid->rowcount();
    $serialcount = $ridserial->rowcount();

    If ($assetcount > 0) {
            // Perform action for duplicate asset number.
    } elseif ($ridcount > 0) {
            // Perform action for duplicate radio ID number.
    } elseif ($serialcount > 0) {
            // Perform action for duplicate serial number.
    } else {
            // No duplicates found, continue with data processing.
    }
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: `WHERE Portable_Asset_Number = X OR Portable_LID = Y OR Portable_Serial_Number = Z` would be the way to construct it as a single query. Then you'd have to examine the values returned in each row and compare to the input values to see which value (or multiple values potentially) are the duplicates. So a bit of PHP processing required for that, but probably still a bit more efficient than three separate SQL queries. I'm not quite sure what kind of feedback you have to give if the duplication occurs in different rows.

Comment: Seriously:  "Don't worry about 'efficiency.'  Only worry about 'correctness.'"  Use parameterized queries one at a time and use as many queries as you wish to make the code *obvious, clear, and correct.*

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated the code in the original question. Does the new method of adding the variable to the SELECT statement satisfy SQL Injection prevention methods?

Comment: That is much better.